# In Excel, format header row's color based on last cell value in a consecutive range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm probably overthinking this, but I've been at it for hours and can't get this to work.

My worksheet is set up as a contact log, where some rows (ones which contain an ID# in column A) serve as "headers". Underneath each "header" row, I am logging dates in column B. Normally, header rows are green. But I'd like Excel to check the last date in column B under each "header" (e.g., 5/24/16 for ID# 101, 5/13/16 for ID# 102, etc.). If the last date is more than 1 week old from today's date (currently 5/25/16), I want the "header" row to turn red:

```
A            B
ID#          DATE
101 (green)
             5/1/16
             5/20/16
             5/24/16
102 (red)
             5/2/16
             5/13/16
103 (green)
             5/7/16
             5/19/16
```

And if I were to add a row and enter today's date under 102, the header row would change back to green.

```
A            B
ID#          DATE
101 (green)
             5/1/16
             5/20/16
             5/24/16
102 (green)
             5/2/16
             5/13/16
             5/25/16
103 (green)
             5/7/16
             5/19/16
```

I'm comfortable using conditional formatting for the color change, but I'm really struggling to figure out a formula that will reference the last value in a limited range of values (in column B). I hope that makes sense, and any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: There may be an Excel guru who can give you a pure Excel answer, but I would guess that doing this would require VBA (Visual Basic for Excel).

Comment: That may be the case but thought I'd check all the same. Getting some additional feedback that seems to be on the right track, so fingers crossed. Thanks for your thought though.

Answer (score 1):

Give A2 a default green fill, then select A2 and add a formula-based conditional format with a red fill:

```
 =OFFSET(B2,IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,A3:A40<>"",0)-1, COUNTA(B3:B40)),0)<(TODAY()-7)
```

Extend the "A40" to the point where you'd expect it to cover the max number of dates you'd expect in a single block (ie it needs to include *at least* the next "header").

You can copy > pastespecial > formats to extend the CF to other header cells

[image]

The IFERROR, COUNTA is there to cover the case where there are no more "headers" below, so we just count the number of values in ColB instead (assuming there's nothing else below them in that column)

Not extensively tested, but does seem to work

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is _very_ close. The only problem is it seems as though when I add additional headers, only the last header will revert to green when a recent date (i.e., within 7 days) is added below that header. All the other headers above remain red, regardless of the dates entered under that header (so using your example, 101 remains red, while 103 changes to green when I add 6/1/16). It seems like you didn't encounter this problem? Though I don't understand all the inner workings of your formula, I think I've followed it accurately, so not sure where the problem lies...

Comment: I'm not seeing that problem.  Example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc70r99klbyzo2z/Date%20header%20CF%20example.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for sending the example. I figured out the issue. I was including blank rows below each header, thinking the formula would only check for dates below the header row until a blank (null) value was encountered (my mistake; limited experience with arrays). So in your example, I initially had B4 thru B7 blank, thinking that A2 would change color as I changed the date for only B3. But your formula works great as long as the final cell in each section is filled. I can definitely work with this, so thank you again!